# Is dictionary in Python can be seen as Map in C++

Tags: c++, python

Is dictionary in Python can be seen as Map in C++

And the insert complexity is constant time?
and what about sort complexity of dictionary?
What about iteration?

Need some good points or link to good resource.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the C++ map implementation uses a tree, so insertion and retrieval is O(log(n)) as opposed to O(1).

Python uses hashtables, so retrieval is O(1).

Answer (score 2):

Python dicts are an implementation of the generic data structure commonly referred to as a hash table or hash map.

For Python dicts, complexities are what you would expect from an efficient implementation of a hash table; insert is constant time; iteration is O(N). Dictionaries are unsorted; if you want something that's sorted you generally transform it into something else (like a list).