# c++ map<int, int> in python

Tags: python, c++, dictionary

Does anyone know the c++ equivalent on python? Initially I thought I could replicate this by initializing a simple array on python, but it obviously does not do the same. Any ideas?

```
map<int, int>
```

Kind Regards and many thanks,

Rodrigo

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496911/is-dictionary-in-python-can-be-seen-as-map-in-c

Comment: For those looking for Python's equivalents for sorted sets, multisets, and maps, see [**sortedcontainers**](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/), mentioned in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953205/why-are-there-no-sorted-containers-in-pythons-standard-libraries and available with `pip install sortedcontainers` . multimaps are mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731971/is-there-a-multimap-implementation-in-python#1731989

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Managed to get it sorted. Some syntax errors we all missed but here's the correct way:

```
elevators = {}

elevators['clone_floor'] = clone_pos
```

This works.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Yes but remember that python objects are not statically typed so a declaration like this map is not needed (and would not work)
What you do in python is declare an empty dictionary and add ints to it.

Example:

```
my_map = {} #empty dictionary
my_map[1] = 100
my_map[2] = 150
```

But there would be no problem continuing adding objects of different types to the dictionary:

```
my_map[3] = "Hello world"
```

and changing the type of the existing objects:

```
my_map[1] = "Hello again"
```

Comment: That's equivalent to `unordered_map<int, int>`. It's not sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

```
elevators = {}
clone_floor, clone_pos = map(int, raw_input().split())
elevators[clone_floor] = clone_pos
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's equivalent to `unordered_map<int, int>`. It's not sorted.

Answer (score -1):

It is called a dictionary. One of the most powerful features in Python. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for the documentation.

```
d = dict()
d[1] = 5
d[5] = 2
print d[1]
print d[5]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
elevators = {}
elevatorFloor, elevatorPos = map(int, raw_input().split())
elevators[elevatorFloor] = elevatorPos
```

This should work in Python 2.

Comment: Hey, @Shreevardhan

I tried doing this but the console gives me an error, states it is not a function.

Comment: @RodrigoCarrilho Guess: remove variables named `map` and `int` from your code.

Comment: @RodrigoCarrilho It works for me. State the exact error that you are getting.

Comment: @Shreevardhan that was the exact error. However, now it seems to be resolved. It should now be a syntax mistake with the rest of the code, this bit is now solved. Thanks